# How can I use these two bijections to form a bijection $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Build a bijection $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$  by using the two following known biections $\varphi:{\mathbb{N}} \to {\mathbb{N}} \times {\mathbb{N}}$ and $\psi:{\mathbb{R}}  \to \{0,1\}^{{\mathbb{N}}}$.

**Edit.**

My solution.

Use  the classical bijection $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}.$ Now construct a bijection  $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$  by 
$$
\Phi(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n, \ldots)=\varphi(...\varphi(\varphi(x_1,x_2),x_3)...)
$$

I know  that it doesnt use those two proposed bijections but 
is it   correct?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I like this question.

Comment: @KyleGannon: "The question does not show any research effort". I can completely understand the downvote.

Comment: @Michael: Tons of questions on this site don't show any effort :)

Comment: Turn the given bijections around (i.e. use their inverses) and divide $R^n$ into unit hypercubes.

Comment: I think that I posted at least three or four answers to that question. Either in form of a hint more relevant for actual bijections; or in the form of cardinal arithmetic (which are just neat ways for talking about bijections).

Comment: @KyleGannon Therefore, tons of questions on this site get downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: @Behavior: Then, for some inexplicable reason, they rise again.

Comment: I have added my solution. Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: think about the problem from a different angle; you're looking for a bijection

$$(2^{\Bbb N})^{\Bbb N}\xrightarrow{\sim} 2^{\Bbb N}\dots $$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Note that $\mathbb R^\omega=(2^\omega)^\omega=2^{\omega^2}=2^\omega=\mathbb R$. If you can find a bijection for each equality, composing them should give you your desired bijection.